# Как верстальщику оформлять js код?

Tags: javascript, frontend

На данный момент я пишу js код очень криво.

Как правило, это один файл script.js, в котором я пишу куски кода, оборачивая их в try catch. Если мне нужны табы, то я делаю блок для табов, если это выезжающие по нажатию блоки, то описываю это поведение в отдельном try catch, а мне бы хотелось оформлять свой код более качественно, делая функционирующее приложение, а не непонятный набор рванных кусков JavaScript'a!

Ещё хуже обстоит ситуация с многостраничный и сайтами. Там я вообще каждый интерактив описываю по-новой, и это могут быть одни табы, но на разных страницах их верстка может отличаться, поэтому я переписываю уже существующий код под новую ситуацию. Если нужно, могу поделиться файлами, чтобы было наглядное пособие, от чего я хочу избавиться.

P.S. сильно не ругайте только, я же начинающий ещё, хочу разобраться с этой наболевшей темой))

Comment: А вы пишете код на каком-то фреймворке или просто html+js?

Comment: В вёрстке относительно простого сайта без разницы как что делать. Там не настолько серьёзная ситуация, чтобы выделять какие-то общие части и думать, что делаешь приложение. А если есть желание эти части как-то выделить и унифицировать, то можно делать это как угодно, например код табов сделать классом или просто одной функцией как метод ajax в jQuery. Как-то структурировать можно когда есть на это потребность, а не просто потому что так говорят.

Comment: ИМХО все зависит от долгосрочной перспективы. Если вам надо сверстать сайт, потом поддерживать его, время от времени возвращаться к нему, что-то допиливать и обновлять то имеет смысл качественно писать и структурировать код. Так вам буде легче сопровождать и поддерживать сайт. В долгосрочной перспективе это вырастет в экономию времени и денег. А если вам надо просто сделать сайт и навсегда о нем забыть, то не имеет значения как делать.

Comment: Для небольших проектов можно оставить как есть, лишь бы работало. Чтобы понять, как правильно разрабатывать что-то серьезное, посмотри исходники web-приложений на Github. 
Еще про оформление кода - прочитай про [Airbnb style guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript). Для проверки кода на соответствие правилам оформления и поиска ошибок можно использовать eslint, для автоформатирования  - prettier.